# RemoteAction retrieve controller variables

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a page, in which when it loads i want it to fill a table with data. I decided to use the same controllers between the two because the data needed for the page is the same. However by doing this the constructor never occurs because it is the same page.

I decided to create a remoteaction that would trigger on page load. However after setting up the remoteAction since the method is static it no longer has access to the controllers objects. Is there anyway to get the controllers objects from the remoteAction

```
public class foo{

public string x {get; set;}
@remoteaction
public void foobar{
     x = 'we';}}
```

x is not accessible. Is there any work arounds or am i looking at passing parameters along through the page.

Comment: Why does the constructor need to be called again?

Comment: It doesn't have to, i am trying to make sure something occurs when another page loads with the same controller

Comment: In that case, try an actionFunction that you can call on page load.